# Advice needed with optimization when solving Kata's

Tags: ruby, optimization, runtime

I'm doing Katas at codewars and I on occasion pass all the tests but fail due to timeout reasons. Could you please help with comments on how to improve my code by refactoring the code below.

`arrA` and `arrB` are arrays, `rng` is a range and `wanted` is either "odd" or "even". I need to return an array that holds numbers that exists more than once in each array, and is within the range and is either odd or even.

```
def find_arr(arrA, arrB, rng, wanted)
  common = arrA && arrB

  range = (rng[0]..rng[1]).to_a.select {|num| common.include?(num)}

  range_wanted = range.select {|num| wanted == "odd" ? num.odd? : num.even?}

  numbers_twice = range_wanted.select {|num| arrA.count(num) > 1 && arrB.count(num) > 1}
end
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a "Question & Answer" forum. You're asking for general consulting or tutoring on a subject (optimization), which is a covered extensively, and easily found, with a search of the Internet. Your question is likely to be down-voted and left unanswered, unless you show further effort and make your question more specific.  For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: I don't think this asks for "general consulting or tutoring" at all. The question is precise and clear: Which part of the code is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of issues here, mainly time complexity is O(n^2) because of the last line which counts number occurrences in both arrays. For each number in `range_wanted` it needs to iterate over all elements of both arrays. This is highly inefficient.

Try to run your code in irb with those arguments `find_arr([], [], [1, 10_000_000], "odd")` or bigger range.

Here are some suggestions how to improve this code:

1. Count occurrences yourself by storing them in a hash
2. When counting you can skip those numbers that don't meet requirements, range and odd/even
3. If you want to check if value is in a range, you should use `cover?` method from `Range` class. Do not change range into array and iterate over it.
4. In this line `range_wanted = range.select {|num| wanted == "odd" ? num.odd? : num.even?}` you are testing `wanted == "odd"` in every iteration, but this won't ever change as it is passed as argument. You can move this condition outside of loop

Here is refactored code. I wrote it out of my head, so there may be some issues but it should give you an idea on how to write your own solution.

```
def find_arr(arrA, arrB, rng, wanted)
  countA = Hash.new(0)
  countB = Hash.new(0)

  # If wanted == "odd" we want to test elem % 2 == 1, otherwise elem % 2 == 0
  remainder = wanted == "odd" ? 1 : 0
  range = (rng[0]..rng[1])

  arrA.each do |elem|
    if range.cover?(elem) && (elem % 2 == remainder)
      countA[elem] += 1
    end
  end

  arrB.each do |elem|
    if range.cover?(elem) && (elem % 2 == remainder)
      countB[elem] += 1
    end
  end

  result = []

  countA.each do |elem, count|
    if count > 1 && countB[elem] > 1
      result.push(elem)
    end
  end

  result
end
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This gives me some great ideas and new methods to  practice on. Cheers